# Qt Qml in a normal Qt application

Tags: c++, qt4, viewmodel, qml

I have a QListView with a custom ListviewDelegate::paint implemented to do custom painting of items.

I wonder if its possible to crete a qml file defining a rectangle and use that for painting each item? This would give me some freedom to create decent looking items in my listview compared to using the QPainter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like its possible. using following code you can load QML element as QDeclarativeView. Which is derived from QWidget, so you can paint that widget from your deletegate.

```
 QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView;
 qmlView->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqml.qml"));
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the qml that are shown are just all white. No content are shown

Comment: Didnt see the error output in output window. Solved it and yes the items are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Derive from a `QDeclarativeItem` and override `paint` method. Register this new component with `qmlRegisterType` and use it inside your delegate.

Don't forget to unset flag `QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents` in your custom component item.

Component code:

```
class CustomItem : public QDeclarativeItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (int radius READ radius WRITE setRadius)
public:
    explicit CustomItem(QDeclarativeItem *parent = 0)
      : QDeclarativeItem(parent), m_radius(0)
    {
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents, false);
    }
    void paint(QPainter *, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *);
    void setRadius(int r);
    int radius();
private:
    int m_radius;
};
```

Viewer code (inside main, before setting QML source):

```
qmlRegisterType<CustomItem>("Self", 1,0, "CustomItem");
```

And QML code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import Self 1.0
ListView {
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { name: "One";   value: 10 }
        ListElement { name: "Two";   value: 5 }
        ListElement { name: "Three"; value: 15 }
    }
    delegate: Column {
        Text {
            text: name
        }
        CustomItem {
            radius: value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that not the inverse of what i asked? I want to in my QtGui application to load a QML item and use as the item for my QListView?

Comment: What is Self 1.0 in the import Self 1.0 ?

Comment: Sorry, I have misinterpreted the question. "Self" is an arbitrary QML module name used with `qmlRegisterType`.